# Is it okay if JQuery can't find a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using JQuery [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) in order to have nice tables throughout my web application, but it's getting to be cumbersome to make changes and deployments across all of the different files that have a table in it.

```
$(function(){
     $("#exampleTable").dataTable({
         "stateSave": true,
         "stateDuration": -1
     });
 })
```

I came up with the idea to simply include the same JavaScript file in all of the documents that have a DataTable which initializes all of the different tables from one place.

Obviously from page to page most of the elements won't actually exist on that page, and so JQuery will be unable to find them.

My question is: is this okay? Are there any ramifications? I like to think that this is the ideal solution, but want to make sure that there won't be any problems. Appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I suppose that I could just give every table I want DataTable'd a certain class, and have the declaration on that whole class in the JavaScript file, so there would be less / no unfound objects. But the question still stands. I am hoping for a fairly reputable answer in terms of how it could affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine if you try to run datatables on non-existent elements, most jQuery plugins work by iterating over each element in the current jQuery collection and applying some operation. If the collection is empty, it will just return. It won't have any performance impact (other than what DataTables already adds *only when it actually is applied to a table*).

**Edit**: I looked through the source and they do apply a set of methods to `this` before running through `this.each` to apply the actual dataTables functionality to each element in the collection. This still shouldn't impact performance though as they aren't calling any of the methods: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L5333-L6108

Answer (score 0):

In terms of functionality, this won't cause any problems. The jQuery selector will search, find nothing (hopefully) and then execute the commands on nothing.

This is bad if you can't be sure that someone else won't create an element with this ID on another page. Also, if this practice becomes rampant and you have tons of irrelevant commands firing on all your pages, it will start to slow down your website.